# Transform API response in Angular rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, api, rxjs

Hi I've this response from API:

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "motivazione":"",
         "autorizzazione":false,

      }
   ]
}
```

How do I transform it like this:

```
[
      {
         "id":1,
         "motivazione":"",
         "autorizzazione":false,

      },
   ]
```

Thanks

Joseph

Comment: What's the relation between this and Angular or RXjs? Also you are developing an Angular app with Observables and all, but you have no idea how to extract an element from an array or an object? Friendly advice, perhaps you should take a few "Javascript 101" tutorials before tackling Angular :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't clear. If all you need is to get the contents of the property `records`, you could pipe a `pluck` operator to the HTTP request.

```js
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';

public someFunction(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(
    pluck('records')
  );
}
```

Alternatively you could also use the `map` operator.

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

public someFunction(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(
    map((res: any) => res['records'])
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the map operator in rxjs to transform your data. More precisely if you only want the records property from your response object you can do that as following: 

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

transformData(){
     this.http.get(url).pipe(map((target: any) => target.records)).subscribe((data) => {
   console.log(data);
    })}
```

This will return only the record property from your response object.

Comment: You can't return value from inside the subscription's callback.

Comment: @MichaelD Yes !! Fixed it.